# How to create Countdown timer in Android till a specific date

Tags: android, countdown

I am creating an app for an event in the future and want a countdown till that date and time.
i have checked many questions regarding this but couldn't find the exact code for that. I want that app would take time from system and subtract that from the future time and gets updated every second.

Answer (score 3):

Simply create a new Date and convert it to time, pass the time to the CountDownTimer and wait

you can do it this way

```
SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dformat.parse("20-09-2014"); // change this to your date
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //      .getTime() does the conversion: Date --> long
    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(date.getTime(), 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }.start();
```

> the onTick method will be triggred every 1s you can change that by
>   changing the 1000 value in the second paramater of the COuntDownTimer
>   constructor

Comment: and the required conversions to hours minutes and seconds will be done in OnTick class ?

Comment: Yes you can do it there or u can do it at the end in the Onfinish() method

Comment: But it is showing an error, it says change the Date modifier to 'final' for conversions in onTick class and shows error that there should not be 'final' with Date for the code in try{} .

Comment: Change it to final but make the conversion in OnFinish dont convert onTick  only if u want to notify every 1s

Comment: The problem is that if I change it to final, the date variables in try{} will show error. If I don't use final the date variables in OnTick or OnFinish will show error.